# One div fadeOut, wait, another div animate

Tags: jquery

How can I make #blue animate only when #red has fadeOut completely? I mean:
1. red fadeOut
2. wait 1 second
3. blue animate...

```
$(function(){     
    $("#blue").click(function() {
        $("#red").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#blue").animate({top:'20px'},"slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow"); 
    }); 
})
```

You can play and try here: http://jsfiddle.net/J8PVZ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fadeout` callback and move `delay` before `animate` : http://jsfiddle.net/J8PVZ/1/

```
$(function(){     
    $("#blue").click(function() {
        $("#red").fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $("#blue").delay(1000).animate({top:'20px'},"slow").fadeOut("slow");     
        });
    }); 
})
```

Comment: But what about the step 2? Can I control the time between step 1 and step 3?

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle I made? Isn't it what you are expecting?

Comment: Exactly what callbacks are for... you can manage timing with delays but it's not as flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know about the callback function of `fadeOut()` as shown in the docs here:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

You also need to delay before you animate.

```
$(function(){
    $("#blue").click(function() {
        $("#red").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#blue").delay(1000).animate({top:'20px'},"slow").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve with fadeout callback function and with use of `.promise().done()`:

<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/J8PVZ/2/</kbd>

```
$("#blue").click(function () {
    $("#red").fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function(){
        $("#blue").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

use the callback method

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

        $("#blue").bind('click',function() {        
        $("#red").fadeOut("slow",function(){        
            $("#blue").animate({top:'20px'},"slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
            });
        });
    }
    );
```